# Error occur while install ubuntu 12.04

Tags: partitioning

[image]

While i install ubuntu 12.04 on installation type screen display info. like Your installation medium is on /dev/sdb1 ... can seen in screenshot.

if anyone know this problem then help me.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu HDD name system `sda` is first HDD and `sdb` is Second HDD.
And I see one HDD on this screenshot this `sda` not `sdb`.

You must choose second HDD and user first partition for install on `sdb1`.
And some action you need for install on that partition.